# Check if particular action or filter exists in a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check if any action/filter exists in the Wordpress theme.

I have tried `has_action` and `has_filter`. But the problem with these functions is that if the hook/filter exists and no callbacks are added to the hook or all callbacks are removed from the hook, these will return false.

Comment: I don't think you can check if an action or filter exists. Be more specific about what are you trying to do. If the actions/filters are specific for a plugin, there are other ways to test their existence. If the actions/filters are from wordpress core, you can check the wordpress version they were implemented.

Comment: I was talking about the filter/hooks in Wordpress core. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @andreivictor good advice, however OP(original poster) is reffering to a non-core filter:  "`action/filter exists in the Wordpress theme`" which is probably reffering to some not-wordpress-default theme :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is not an built-in Wordpress function that will check for this. But you would be able to check if a filter exists using the following code:

```
// check for the existence of "the_content" filter
if( array_key_exists( 'the_content' , $GLOBALS['wp_filter']) ) {
}
```

The problem with this is that it will only check if the filter exists *at the point at which the above code runs*.  So if the above code runs in a plugin, and a filter is added in a theme template file (which happens later in execution order, it won't show up yet.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem, because if filter does not exist yet, it just does not exist... :-)

Comment: This does not work to check a filter available because if a callback is attached to a filter it will show in the array even if the filter is not available